# ASP.NET: debugging in same directory than publishing

Tags: asp.net

I want to debug my asp.net application in same directory than I publish, so absolute paths are the same as real environment.

I try to activate use local IIS in "Web" properties but I get an error saying: I need to create virtual directory (actually it already exists in that directory) and if I try to creat it I get a cryptic error saying there is already a different folder assigned (or something similar)

Thank you

Comment: what do u mean in same directory? as long as i remembered for debugging asp.net, i just pressed f5 and ran normally.any other detailed information?

Answer (score 0):

You mean to debug from the local IIS or any remote server directly right?

Close the VS. Open the `.sln` file in notepad, there will be a line on top like

```
Project("{random numbers}") = "test", "..\..\WebSites\test\", "{random numbers}"
```

Change the second parameter (relative path of your project folder in file system) to the address of your virtual directory. Like:

```
Project("{random numbers}") = "test", ""http://localhost/test/"", "{random numbers}"
```

Also if you are using IIS7, change the virtual directory to application.

Comment: yes, taht's what I mean, debug in my localhost. There's no "test" in my sln file, I have this: 
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "_nzine", "_nzine.vbproj", "{8AD2D1D5-1462-40C9-95FD-ECF7F9D2D1C3}"

Comment: ... replace this -> "_nzine.vbproj" with iis path .I never done in vb.hope it works.Alternatively from VS, clcik on File>open>open a website .. Now select Local IIS and the virtual directory , click open.. save this solution with current name.

Mark it as answer if  works. :)

Comment: It didn't work, don't try this at home! Now I have a little chaos here ;-)